# Parsing a Boost:Tuple into a char* (with endianess)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, boost-fusion, boost-tuples

I have many classes with varying implementations of their private member `boost::tuple<> structures` ie. `<std::string, int>` or `<short, short, float>`.
I now need to parse that tuple into a private `const char* message` (since I want to send it via tcp), but not without changing the endianess on those data types that need their endianess changed.

This i what I have so far:

```
struct parseTuple{
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T& t) const{
        std::cout << ntohl(t) << "\n";
    }
};

void Base::createMessageFromTuple(){
    boost::fusion::for_each(this->structure, parseTuple());
}
```

There are a few things I think I need to know before I can proceed:

1. How to keep track of the tuple members so i can allocate space for the `message` according to their datatypes (static member, maybe?)
2. How to differentiate in the template between the datatypes that fit the `ntohl` requirements and those that need different treatment i.e. `std::string`
3. Is this even the correct approach?

Comment: Generally speaking, "parse" means reading a data structure from a string,... sort of...it's a part of deserialization.  Writing to a string generally doesn't involve parsing and is usually simply termed "serialization".

Comment: consider using boost::serialization

Comment: thank you. I'm sorry for the wording problem - I do now see that I meant serialization. Even though I can not find anything usable in boost::serialization to get a boost::tuple into a stream of characters. Would you mind pointing me into the right direction, please? Because so far I still find it easier to iterate trough the tuple and append the strings.